# Адаптивная верстка сайта. Сдвиг картинок

Tags: css

Как правильно сгрупировать блоки с картинками так, что при переходе с ПК на мобильную версию сайта большой блок был на 3 месте сверху? (смотрите на примеры ниже.)

[image: ьлоки на пк]

[image: блоки на мобильном]

Comment: добавтье код я вам помогу

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется что такой подход не профессиональный

Я лишь показал как манипулировать...смотрите

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bKNMVP)  здесь можно подвигать окошко, проверить как перестраиваются блоки

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.items {
  width: 630px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 420px;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(4),
.item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate(0, -210px);
}

@media (max-width:645px) {
  .items {
    width: 420px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .item:nth-child(4),
  .item:nth-child(5) {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .items {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .item {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    float: none;
  }
  img {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="items clear">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/cccc00" alt=""> </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/cc00cc" alt=""> </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x410/cc0000" alt=""> </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ccc000" alt=""> </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/000ccc" alt=""> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хороший ответ! полезний код.

Answer (score 1):

Уже самое время начинать активно пользоваться гридами для верстки таких раскладок и делать обратные фоллбеки для старых браузеров.

Ключевые строчки:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
```

`auto-fill` активирует автозаполнение колонок, не привязанное к их количеству.
`minmax()` — функция, которая задаёт минимальную и максимальную ширину колонки, в данном случае запись означает, что колонка должна быть минимум 150 пикселей в ширину и максимум 1 часть от всех колонок в строке.

```
grid-row: span 2;
```

Это свойство позволяет растянуть блок по высоте на 2 строки.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.conditions-grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.condition {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

.condition--span {
  grid-row: span 2;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="conditions-grid">
  <article class="condition">1</article>
  <article class="condition">2</article>
  <article class="condition condition--span">3</article>
  <article class="condition">4</article>
  <article class="condition">5</article>
</section>
```

Comment: как это реализовать в старых браузерах?

Comment: Добавить через `@supports not (display: grid) { ... }` условия, которые реализуют подобное. Впоследствии, при улучшении поддержки браузерами, этот код просто выпиливается.